# Ubuntu Add/upload folder permissions

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm hosting a simple PHP Script which creates folders and uploads images, it has a simple admin page (serverip/admin).

I tested the scripts in my local server and it works perfectly, but in my server it doesn't and I believe it's a permissions issue.

my /var/www/ folder permissions:

```
root@WallApi:/var/www/html# ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1 Jul 13 00:56 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 13 00:55 Script
root@WallApi:/var/www/html#
```

I have no group users I simply want to be able to upload / create etc. using the script

Comment: Check your error logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using LAMP you should change the permission owner to apache user or change permission to 777.

1) Change owner

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
```

2) Change perssmion ( not recommend)

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
```

**p/s update**

The permissions on this folder are:

```
chmod 755 /var/www/
```

and the files inside the folder are:

```
chmod 644 /var/www/file
```

The default permission for /var/www itself is a pretty standard one: owner root:root and mod 755.

As for anything inside /var/www, that is one of the rare directories where you have the privilege of deciding for yourself what to put in it and what permissions everything in it should have. But what makes the most sense is:

Most files should be writable by whichever user or group is going to be writing to them most. You can set them to be owned by your user account. Or set up a custom group for your developers. Or if the files will be modified rarely and you want good security, you can go with root:root and just sudo in on the rare occasions they'll be modified.
Most files should not be world-writable. So, 644 for files, and 755 for directories is appropriate (or 664 and 775 if you want to give a group write access).
It is not recommended to set any of it to be writable by the web server, ie www-data, except for any specific files your web scripts to be able to write to. If so, it's better to set the user or group of those files to www-data than to make them world-writable. Note that any time the www-data user can write to any file within the web root, whether it's by setting the user or group on those files, or making them world-writable, it's a potential security problem. World-writable is just the worse of the two.

Comment: 777 for all users is very unsecure

Comment: I changed the permissions even to 777 but i still cannot create or upload

Comment: Did it show any error or could you show us your create/upload code?

Comment: its a php script downloaded from Evanto it works perfectly in my local

Comment: What OS environment in your local ?  Could you tell me that link from Evanto ? 

OR you could check the apache error logs 

1 ) RHEL / Red Hat / CentOS / Fedora Linux Apache access file location –
/var/log/httpd

2 ) Debian / Ubuntu Linux Apache access log file location –

/var/log/apache2

3) FreeBSD Apache access log file location –

 /var/log

Comment: Please note that now i can upload but i cannot create folders

Comment: its a Ubuntu 14.04 , and my local is windows 8 wamp server

Comment: ah you said you can upload , did it mean your upload file was uploaded to server. Did you check your upload file is store or not on server . 
i don't know your upload code so I can't know why you can't create folder. Therefore for better ways you should check the error logs file for more detail

Comment: i did check the error log on /var/log but i couldn't find anything  and in my local wamp server in my windows everything works fine

Comment: it add it like this     `if(!is_dir('categories/'.$cat_id))
    {
 
      mkdir('categories/'.$cat_id, 0777);

      mkdir('categories/'.$cat_id.'/thumbs', 0777);
    }`

Comment: tried do this 

`$path =  getcwd().'categories/'.$cat_id; 
if(!is_dir($path)) mkdir($path, 0777)`

Comment: mmmm I tried on my server, it worked 
Please tried again , i missed some part 
https://paste.ofcode.org/GgZh87eHtEW8wPFJqLQRyC
And could you print `!is_dir($categoryPath)`